# Getting a 500 error on executing a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to execute a prepared statement as follows:

```
$usersStmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT :startAt,:pageSize"); 
$usersStmt->bindParam (':startAt', $startAt);
$usersStmt->bindParam (':pageSize', $pageSize);

$usersStmt->execute ();
```

But this gives me a 500 error. Is the comma in the SQL query a problem ?

Comment: afaik `bindParams` is not supposed to use with `LIMIT` parameters.

Comment: HTTP 500 error?  That generally indicates a server error.  But some service providers may have that error thrown for programming errors as well (mine does).

Comment: @u_mulder As of MySQL 5.0.7, placeholders can be used for the arguments of the LIMIT clause when using prepared statements.

Comment: Always check return values from prepare() and execute(), they return **false** if there's an error. If that happens, check the error and report it (or log it).

Comment: Check your server's error log for details about the 500.

Answer (score 0):

No.

[It's the way you are binding your variables or the emulation mode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15991623)

Note that $startAt and $pageSize have to be of int type already.

Also, you have to develop a habit of **peeking into error log.** "500 error" is not for you. Its for a browser and a search engine. It says nothing on the error but only indicates that there was one. But **PHP has a textual explanation of the error for you** which you are expected to read and comprehend. You, but noone else. this is why in a live environment errors get logged, not shown to everyone.